# SSIS Package DB Connection check

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which has a connection to a database. I took the database down to test a scenario, but the package gives me the following error in the output window when starting the package when the DB is offline:

SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DBNAME" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

I need to check the connection when the package is run and notify a user, via email, that the DB is down. How would I go about doing this?

I have the code to send the email, I just need to do the DB check when the package is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnally got it working. What I did was, create an XML file with the database settings, data source, initial catalog etc. Then added a script task, added some code to read the settings from the XML file and create a SQLConnection and connect to the DB in a try catch. If there is an error send an email, and in the finnaly closed the SQL connection.

But to get this working you HAVE to ensure that you connection has the property 'DelayValidation' set to TRUE. If not the package will fail to aquire a connection before the script task gets executed.

Comment: Can you share the script please?

Answer (score 1):

Use a script task. Try to open a connection to your database and if it fails then Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure.

A great post about this issue here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7de0216b-3a0a-40ce-8149-f566a05010c9/ssis-check-database-connection-and-if-disconnected-send-email-alert?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: The problem is the as soon as my package starts it does not do anything as it cannot aquire a connection to the database.

Comment: you don't need to add a datasource to your package. just add a script task.

Comment: I've tried that and it does not help. It does not go into the script task, it just starts and finishes saying : SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DBNAME" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: drop everything from your connection manager.. you don't need it !

Comment: I do as I is being used in a data flow task

Answer (score 1):

Make your DB check occur *outside* of your package. How is the package run? Scheduled in SQL Agent or kicked off by the user? Instead of just running DTEXEC, first run a script that checks connectivity, i.e. using SQLCMD.EXE.

But really a better way is to run the package as normal then check the SSIS logs afterwards and send an appropriate message. Otherwise you'll be cooking up all different kinds of custom pre-execution checks to run.

I'm no batch script expert but here's an example of a bit of code you can use to test connectivity to a SQL Server and call another batch script if it fails, otherwise run the package with DTEXEC.

```
SQLCMD -S YOurServer -E -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      CALL YourEmailScript.CMD
)
ELSE
(
DTExec /f "\\pathtodtsxfile\file.dtsx"
)
```

This is not production quality code. I would not recommend calling your DTEXEC in this way, it's just an example.

Comment: I am ruunning the file via a batch file like this:

DTExec /f "\\pathtodtsxfile\file.dtsx"